# Access control allow origin in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

controller.js

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'here API url',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     data: data
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     if (response.data) {
         sharedServices.set(response.data);
     }
     console.log(response);
 }, function errorCallback(response) {
     if (response) {
         $scope.message = response.data;
     }
 });
```

This is my controller file.
Error in browser console
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load "here API url".No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: This is something you need to configure on the server side

Comment: @ yarons yes i added in server side and its working in postman perfectly.In any browser it throws above error.